# Run all Python scripts in a folder - from Python

Tags: python, cross-platform

How can I write a Python program that runs all Python scripts in the current folder? The program should run in Linux, Windows and any other OS in which python  is installed.

Here is what I tried:

```
import glob, importlib

for file in glob.iglob("*.py"):
    importlib.import_module(file)
```

This returns an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'agents.py'; 'agents' is not a package`
(here `agents.py` is one of the files in the folder; it is indeed not a package and not intended to be a package - it is just a script).

If I change the last line to:

```
    importlib.import_module(file.replace(".py",""))
```

then I get no error, but also the scripts do not run.

Another attempt:

```
import glob, os

for file in glob.iglob("*.py"):
    os.system(file)
```

This does not work on Windows - it tries to open each file in Notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that you are running the script through the command line. To do this you need to add `python3` plus the name of the file that you are running. The following code should work

```
import os
import glob

for file in glob.iglob("*.py"):
    os.system("python3 " + file)
```

If you are using a version other than python3, just change the argument from `python3` to `python`

Comment: What if one platform has python3 while another platform has python.exe? Is it possible to get the executable of the current python interpreter?

Comment: That is possible with `sys.executable`.

Comment: I believe that you can do that with `sys.executable`. For more information, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi you can just call "python", '/usr/bin/python' is the symbolic link to installed version of python

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make use of the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module; this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) shows a few options.

Your code could look like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

base_path = os.getcwd()
print('base_path', base_path)

# TODO: this might need to be 'python3' in some cases
python_executable = 'python'
print('python_executable', python_executable)

py_file_list = []
for dir_path, _, file_name_list in os.walk(base_path):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
            # add full path, not just file_name
            py_file_list.append(
                os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))

print('PY files that were found:')
for i, file_path in enumerate(py_file_list):
    print('   {:3d} {}'.format(i, file_path))

    # call script
    subprocess.run([python_executable, file_path])
```

Does that work for you?

---

Note that the docs for [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) even suggest using `subprocess` instead:

> The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the content of the scripts, perhaps you might consider using a plugin technique, this would bring the problem more into the Python domain and thus makes it less platform dependent. Take a look at [pyPlugin](https://github.com/sourcesimian/pyPlugin) as an example.

This way you could run each "plugin" from within the original process, or using the [Python::multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library you could still seamlessly use sub-processes.